# Ubuntu 18.04.2 is going hang after One/ half an hour cause of chrome and mozilla

Tags: 18.04, updates, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

I have installed the 18.04.2 on two systems and both are having an issue with browsers like Chrome, Chromium and Firefox.

Systems are getting hanged or sometimes very slow after approx one hour.

What may be the possible solutions for this?

Result for inxi -Fxz

```
System:    Host: bigstep Kernel: 4.18.0-18-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu3) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook 
           v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: N/A
           Mobo: HP model: 80C1 v: 96.44 serial: N/A UEFI [Legacy]: Insyde v: F.1E date: 12/25/2015
Battery    BAT1: charge: 26.0 Wh 100.0% condition: 26.0/32.6 Wh (80%) model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 status: Full
 CPU:      Dual core Intel Core i3-5005U (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Broadwell rev.4 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 7982
           clock speeds: max: 1900 MHz 1: 798 MHz 2: 798 MHz 3: 798 MHz 4: 798 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 5500 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.1 ) driver: i915 Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:03.0 Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.18.0-18-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 bus-ID: 07:00.0
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8723be port: 3000 bus-ID: 0d:00.0
           IF: wlp13s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (2.7% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD1 size: 1000.2GB temp: 41C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 437G used: 5.4G (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
           ID-2: /boot size: 547M used: 108M (22%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-3: /opt size: 234G used: 7.4G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4
           ID-4: /home size: 234G used: 3.6G (2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-5: swap-1 size: 10.24GB used: 1.44GB (14%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.5C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 288 Uptime: 1 day Memory: 5906.7/7897.9MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: N/A
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Result: top -n 1 -o %MEM | head -15

```
top - 18:36:46 up 1 day,  8:51,  1 user,  load average: 0.79, 2.31, 4.49
 Tasks: 285 total,   1 running, 227 sleeping,   3 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27.5 us,  6.6 sy,  0.4 ni, 55.1 id,  9.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8087476 total,  1218824 free,  6015740 used,   852912 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 10000380 total,  8599516 free,  1400864 used.  1659212 avail Mem 

  PID    USER      PR    NI     VIRT     RES     SHR  S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+  COMMAND 
  2475   bigstep   20     0  4099960  291452   54384  S   5.0   3.6  63:48.47  skypeforlinux 
 11086   bigstep   20     0   853152  164800  112700  S   0.0   2.0   0:22.15  chrome 
 11560   bigstep   20     0   814492  157964   78896  S   5.0   2.0   1:09.64  chrome 
  2055   bigstep   20     0  3930120  121976   42120  S   0.0   1.5  53:27.32  gnome-shell 
 11125   bigstep   20     0   557600   98468   79648  S   0.0   1.2   0:25.60  chrome 
 11128   bigstep   20     0   552044   81648   58472  S   0.0   1.0   0:02.97  chrome 
  2294   bigstep   20     0  3681628   70656   34708  S   0.0   0.9  30:42.43  skypeforlinux 
 11097   bigstep   20     0   441408   55956   45740  S   0.0   0.7   0:00.22  chrome
```

Result of: top -n 1 -o %CPU | head -15

```
top - 18:38:51 up 1 day,  8:53,  1 user,  load average: 0.85, 1.82, 4.03
Tasks: 285 total,   1 running, 227 sleeping,   3 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27.4 us,  6.5 sy,  0.4 ni, 55.3 id,  8.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8087476 total,  1214376 free,  6018868 used,   854232 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 10000380 total,  8600028 free,  1400352 used.  1657152 avail Mem 

  PID    USER      PR    NI     VIRT     RES    SHR  S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+  COMMAND  
 12244   bigstep   20     0    51316    3848   3080  R  11.8   0.0   0:00.03  top 
     1   root      20     0   225840    3772   2252  S   5.9   0.0   0:52.65  systemd 
  2055   bigstep   20     0  3930220  122116  42116  S   5.9   1.5  53:32.68  gnome-shell 
  2100   bigstep   20     0   364880    7080   2504  S   5.9   0.1   2:03.19  ibus-daemon 
 11560   bigstep   20     0   815592  149516  78980  S   5.9   1.8   1:32.17  chrome 
     2   root      20     0        0       0      0  S   0.0   0.0   0:00.07  kthreadd 
     3   root       0   -20        0       0      0  I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00  rcu_gp 
     4   root       0   -20        0       0      0  I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00  rcu_par_gp
```

Result of : free -h

```
          total   used   free    shared   buff/cache   available
Mem:       7.7G   5.8G   1.1G      156M         840M        1.6G
Swap:      9.5G   1.3G   8.2G
```

Comment: • Install *inxi*, run `inxi -Fxz` and post the output here so people know about your system. • When your system seems pretty slow, run `top -n 1 -o %MEM | head -15` and `top -n 1 -o %CPU | head -15` and post the output here.

Comment: What're the specs on your system?  RAM, gpu, CPU, etc. are all important to know here

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `free -h`.

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/fstab`. Reboot, and then temporarily set `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`, and see if there's any improvement.